# Convert multiple MySQL records to single record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've found similar questions to this, but to clarify I am NOT trying use row values as column headers.

I have a table with the following columns:
**id** = autonumber
**item_id** = the entry id of the form submission
**field_id** = the field id in the submitted form entry
**meta_value** = the submitted value in the form field
**created_at** = datetime

I've seen tutorials to turn the field values into column headers (i.e. field_id1, field_id2, etc.) but I'm actually trying to convert these rows into a cohesive, labeled record.

The column headers would ideally look like this:
**item_id** (primary key)
**Contract Number** (value where field_id = 100 AND item_id = value from the first column)
**Vendor** (value where field_id = 101 AND item_id = value from the first column)
**Type** (value where field_id = 102 AND item_id = value from the first column)
**Scope** (value where field_id = 103 AND item_id = value from the first column)

I know I could achieve this by making a series of mini-queries where it has the item_id and meta_value with criteria set to only show records from a specific field_id, then join them all together in a master query using the item_id to tie it all together. But that seems like an awful approach from a performance standpoint.

If anyone could point me to an example or perhaps help me out with the terminology I should be searching for, I'd greatly appreciate it!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation to piece together your records from your [EAV (Entity Attribute Value)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)  structure

```sql
SELECT item_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 100 THEN meta_value END) contract,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 101 THEN meta_value END) vendor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 102 THEN meta_value END) type,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 103 THEN meta_value END) scope       
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY item_id;
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3e2fa94807f15172f0f8f89f60a6d2af) demo

Comment: Incredible. Thanks so much for the guidance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use  a self join for the  4 values

```
  select 
        t1.item_id
      , t1.meta_value as `Contract Number`
      , t2.meta_value as Vendor
      ,  t3.meta_value as Type
      , t4.meta_value as Scope 
  from my_table t1
  inner join my_table t2 on t1.item_id = t2.item_id and t2.fiedl_id = 101 
  inner join my_table t3 on t1.item_id = t3.item_id and t3.fiedl_id = 102 
  inner join my_table t4 on t1.item_id = t4.item_id and t3.fiedl_id = 103
  where t1.field_id = 100
```